# How to call a variable that is declared in upper class

Tags: java

I tried many ways to call the declared variable 'location' in onCreateView, but it shows me only errors.

First of all, I can't use getIntent() because ArrayListFragment is static class.

Due to lack of my Java knowledge, it's hard to find a way in this case.

Your advice will be very appreciated.

The place where I want to call the variable is annotated below in onCreateView.

```
public class FragmentStatePagerSupport extends FragmentActivity {
MyAdapter myAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
String location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.fragment_pager );

    location = getIntent().getStringExtra( "name" );

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.pager );
    mPager.setAdapter( myAdapter );



}

private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition( object );
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return head_array.length;
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
    int mNum;

    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num){
        ArrayListFragment arrayListFragment = new ArrayListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(  );
        bundle.putInt( "num", num );
        arrayListFragment.setArguments( bundle );
        return arrayListFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt( "num" ) : 1;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false );

        //Here, I want to call a variable 'location' that is declared in FragmentStatePagerSupport class//

        return v;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Do you want to reframe your question. It looks bit confusing your expected behaviour. Second update your question with error you are getting

Comment: 'Upper class'? Do you mean *base* class?

Answer (score 0):

> [It's] because `ArrayListFragment` class is static.

Does it have to be static? If so, pass the location along with the position here

```
ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position, location)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked by passing parameter as you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really big problem here; as you should never make an outer class private because nothing can access it.

If you do not want it to be created multiple times and just once, try making it a Singleton class.

It would also be nice if you added the parent classes, they are very relevant to understanding your idea and object relations. Top-level classes can never be `static`, `private`, `protected`... You don't even have to state that they are public. The only way to make a class with such restrictions is with a nested class.

Anyway, I think that what you might be looking for is adding the modifiers to the local variables. If I'm not wrong, you are trying to pass a String to location, so declare it as such:

```
private String location = getIntent().getStringExtra( "name" );
```

inside the static class declare the variables static. The constructor for `ArrayListFragment` should be non-static as well. Conceptually it does not make sense as well, as the constructor is the same for all classes.

Because of what you are doing, I think you might be trying to make a Singleton. To do so, make a private constructor and a `public static` method (inside the class) that calls that constructor.

Comment: If I make ArrayListFragment not a static class, there will be an error as I need to return static method in getItem() method.